# Add values into a list

Tags: python, list, function, count, global

Hope you're all good. So, I have this code where at the end, I'd like to append values to a global list, but when I call the list, it returns an empty list. It's not adding the values that the function throws.

```py
den = []        # denominador
num_p = []      # numerador play
num_end = []    # numerador end

def Ocurrencias(Datos):
    episodios = []
    global den, num_end, num_p
    for _ in range(len(Datos)):
        x = Datos[_].split(',')
        episodios.extend(x)
    denominador = 0           # abajo
    nominador_p = 0           # arriba
    nominador_e = 0           # arriba
    for i in range(0, len(episodios)-3,4):
        episodios[i]          # estado fuente
        episodios[i+1]        # acción
        denominador += 1
            
        if 'play' in episodios[i+2]:   # estado destino
            nominador_p += 1
        else:
        #elif "end" in episodios[i+2]:
            nominador_e += 1
        episodios[i+3]        # recompensa
    den.append(denominador)     # se supone que debería guardar los valores a la lista
    num_p.append(nominador_p)
    num_end.append(nominador_e)
    x = f"Veces que ocurre (play, continue) : {denominador}" #type: ignore
    y = f"Veces que ocurre (play, continue, play) : {nominador_p}" #type: ignore
    z = f"Veces que ocurre (play, continue, end)  : {nominador_e}"  #type: ignore
    w = f"Probabilidad de (play, continue, play)  : {nominador_p/denominador} "   #type: ignore
    return x, y, z, w
```

Comment: The `Ocurrencias()` function is never called...

Comment: @JohnGordon hahaha i'm so new at this, thanks a lot man!!

Comment: You do not call the function, also try to ask the question in a better way. Most of your code is in Italian I believe and I do not see the global list that you are trying to add data to.